# What will be the time complexity of following recursive algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, master-theorem

What will be the complexity of following recursive algorithm?

```
void rec(n){
 if(n<=0)
    return;
 else
    rec(n/3)+rec(n/2); 
}
```

Comment: its endless? how n can turn to negative or zero?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ: If integral, very easily (`1/2` produces a zero in most languages I know). If float, will take a bit more; if double, longer still (e.g. `1/1e1000` is typically zero). The only way you are in trouble is if you have rational numbers with stretchy integers as nominator and denominator (like Ruby's `Rational`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The time complexity of above program is `O(2 ^ k)`, where k is depth of recursion. 
Here, `2` arises from the fact that in each recursive calls we are giving calls to 2 other recursive calls. Now, lets analyze the deepest depth of recursion (`k`).

[image]

In above figure, the recursive path dividing by 2 in each step will take longer time to reach its value less than 1 (which is base case) and hence it will be the deepest depth of recursion. Since, every time we are dividing `n` by `2`. It will take log steps to reach less than `1`. Although we also divide `n` by `3`. Dividing `n` by `2` will take longer time and hence responsible as a deciding factor for deepest depth of recursion. For details:

> In `1st` call, we reduce n by n / 2.
>  In `2nd` call, we reduce n by
>   (n / 2) / 2 = n / 4 = n / 2^2.
>  Hence, In `Kth` step, we reduce n
>   by :  n / 2^k = 1. 
>  So, n = 2 ^ k.

Taking log base 2 on both sides,

> log2 n = log2 (2^k)
>   log2 n = k log2(2)
>   log2 n =  k * 1              [ since, log2(2) is 1 ]

Therefore, In a deepest depth of recursion, we need `k = log(n)` steps to reach n = 1 and one more step to reach n <= 0. But, overall the depth of recursion will be in between `log3 n` to `log2 n`.

So, overall time complexity is `O(2 ^ log n)` in worst case scenario. But, Since we also divide `n` by `3` and hence all recursive path depth starting from top to leaf node will not be same as that of `log n`. Hence, we can conclude time complexity as `O(2 ^ k)`, where k is depth of recursion.